# Cannot add text (ascii code 0 to 31) into word document using Microsoft.Office.Interop?

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

when i added a string into word document where the string contains ASCII 0 to 31. the string is not stored in word aplication. can anyone tell me what happen here?
for more details look my simple code

```
 dim app As Word.Application
 dim doc As Word.Document
 dim para As Word.Paragraph

    Dim str As String = Chr(26) + "A" + Chr(26) + "A" + Chr(26)

    app= CreateObject("word.application")
    doc= app.Documents.Add
    para= doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    para.Range.Text = str
    doc.SaveAs("d:\zzz.docx")
    app.Quit()

    Dim app As Application = New Application
    Dim doc As Document = app.Documents.Open("d:\zzz.docx")
    Dim str2 As String = doc.Content.Text
    doc.Close()
    app.Quit()
```

str lenght = 5  and  str2 lenght = 2

Comment: ASCII codes 0-31 are non-printable values (mostly control characters). What would you expect them to do in a Word document?

Comment: ASCII 0-31 are not text - they are control codes.  `26` is the code for `SUB` (substitute).  Not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: for cryptography, for example my plaintext is A(65) then after i encrypt it it (ignore crypto algorithm) after my encryption result A(63) will cahange to 26, then i save chr(26) to doc file. @Plutonix

Comment: In your encryption code, add 32 to the value?

Comment: the encryption result its between 0 to 255(affine cipher), btw if word document cannot read or add a unprintable character pls close my post -_- this  is a silly question.